# Barcode in pdf with data from table via php and fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, barcode, fpdf

I want to make student id cards in pdf file and want to generate a barcode for each student which will have their details in it.

My table will be like

Student table

```
Name varchar(55);
Class varchar(20);
RollNo int(4);
Session int(10);
Semester int(4);
Phone int(12);
Address varchar(100);
```

now i want to have only name, class,semester and session in barcode.

Can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [PDFB Library](http://chir.ag/projects/pdfb/) for creating barcodes in PDF format.

Comment: actually PDFB Library is based on FPDF, FPDI and a Barcode Plugin. Hence, it uses some similar functions and dependencies.